Get properties of text objects and delete them in PDF documents
I am doing something similar to an eSign and need to find the text tags (e.g. "{{signature}}") in a PDF document (the page, position in page and the text) and then delete/hide them.  I then need to put a signature image in the saved positions.
I have found and have numerous ways to insert the signature image, but I can't find a way to get the text tag properties and delete it in PHP or with a command line.

I don't have an answer for you at this time, but I can say that if you are searching for "text tags" as it relates to PDFs, you will probably get a lot of unhelpful results. Instead you are searching for arbitrary text and trying to determine the location of each instance. And by location I mean the page number, x/y and probably height and width.
